# Map two variables in one destination from one source with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have want to map two destinations with automapper from the same source variable. It is a DateTime that should be mapped to both interview_start and interview_end.

This is my current code:

```
CreateMap<FromModel, ToModel>()
.ForMember(dest =>
     dest.interview_start,
     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.created_at))
.ForMember(dest =>
    dest.interview_end,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.created_at));
```

What I would like that are written in the same function. As it is easier to understand that those two properties share the same source variable. They are mapped from the same property and it makes the code more readable.

```
CreateMap<FromModel, ToModel>()
.ForMember(dest =>
     (dest.interview_start, dest.interview_end),
     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.created_at))
```

Do anyone know of a better way to map two variables from one variable?

Comment: Honestly, I believe your first example is much more readable and also makes it a lot easier if you ever do decide to change the source for one of them.

Comment: "Easier to understand" is subjective. I personally see nothing wrong declaring each property and their respective source mapping separately.

Comment: I think it is easier/faster to understand that the code has the same source if it is written together. And it removes unnecessary longer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do something like this (I personally don't see any issue with readability of first example), you could come close to what you are looking for with an extension method two effectively wrap two calls to the `ForMember`:

```
public static class AutomapperExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForTwoMembers<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>  mappingExpression, Expression<Func<TDestination, TMember>> destinationMember1, Expression<Func<TDestination, TMember>> destinationMember2, Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember>> memberOptions)
    {
        return mappingExpression
            .ForMember(destinationMember1, memberOptions)
            .ForMember(destinationMember2, memberOptions);
    }
}
```

Your code would end up looking like:

```
CreateMap<FromModel, ToModel>()
.ForTwoMembers(dest1 => dest1.interview_start, dest2 => dest2.interview_end,
     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.created_at))
```

Comment: `params` would help here.